# multiple sql statements

Tags: php, sql

```
$sql = "UPDATE user SET `niveua`='beginner' WHERE `km`< 50";  
$result = $con->query($sql);

$sql = "UPDATE user SET `niveua`='trained' WHERE `km`> 50 or `km` < 99";  
$result = $con->query($sql);

$sql = "UPDATE user SET `niveua`='expert' WHERE `km`> 100";  
$result = $con->query($sql);
```

I can't get those 3 sql's to work. It's only the third one that is updating.
So how do i get all 3 to work?

Comment: simply do select (for test purpose) instead of update in order to check is there any records which match on first two queries. in addition, second query should be `AND`, not `OR`.

Comment: Suggestion: By the way you should use **AND** instead of **OR** in the second query. (**WHERE `km`> 50 AND `km` < 100**)

Answer (score 0):

Missing `AND`, also you can simplify your query like below, so that things can be faster

```
UPDATE user 
SET niveua = 
CASE 
     WHEN (`km` < 50 )
         THEN 'beginner'
     WHEN (`km`> 50 AND `km` < 99 )
         THEN 'trained' 
     WHEN ( `km` > 100 )
         THEN 'expert' 
     ELSE niveua 
END;
```